# Can't write scraped titles into four different sheets in a single csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I have written a script which is writing scraped titles from four different sites into a single sheet of a csv file. Is it possible If I want to write four different titles in four different sheets in a single csv file? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import csv
import requests
from lxml import html

web_list = ['www.dailynews.com','www.dailynews.co.zw','www.gulf-daily-news.com','www.dailynews.gov.bw'] 
outfile=open("title.csv","w",newline='')
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
for websites in web_list:
    url = "http://" + websites
    page = requests.get(url).text
    tree= html.fromstring(page)
    for site_title in tree.xpath("//title"):
        title=site_title.xpath(".//text()")
    writer.writerow(title)
```

Comment: Does the csv file format support 'sheets'?

Comment: No csv file format doesn't support sheets. It is a text file you can visualise using spreadsheets softs. To write files with sheets, you could use ods (libreoffice) with http://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel-ods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with python3 (easier to handle unicode) and the lib mentioned you can transform your code in something like:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data

web_list = ['www.dailynews.com','www.dailynews.co.zw','www.gulf-daily-news.com','www.dailynews.gov.bw'] 
outfile=open("title.csv","w",newline='')

data = {}
for i, websites in enumerate(web_list):
    url = "http://" + websites
    page = requests.get(url).text
    tree= html.fromstring(page)
    for site_title in tree.xpath("//title"):
        title=site_title.xpath(".//text()")
        title.remove('\n')
    data.update({"Sheet"+str(i): [[str(title[0])]]})
save_data("your_file.ods", data)
```

Comment: Thanks mquantin, for your answer. It does the trick what I was after. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Hi mquantin, in your free time you can check out this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131395/unable-to-write-extracted-items-properly-in-an-excel-file"